# Method calls a function to return a value and then the rest of the first function is skipped

Tags: android

I have a function which is supposed to add a new record to the SQLite database. This function will then call a function to return an int to a variable, then the rest of the code is skipped and it goes straight into the finally statement.

Below is the method.

```
    SQLiteDatabase myDb = null;
            if (type.equals("Website"))
            {
                details = formatUrl(details);
            }
            try
            {
                myDb = context.openOrCreateDatabase("PasswordManager", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

                int rowId = common.getNextID("password");

//ALL OF THIS CODE IS SKIPPED
                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put("id", rowId);
                cv.put("category", category);
                cv.put("company", Encryption.encrypt(company));
                cv.put("loginAction", Encryption.encrypt(details));
                cv.put("username", Encryption.encrypt(username));
                cv.put("password", Encryption.encrypt(password));
                cv.put("type", type);
                cv.put("appName", "N/A");
                myDb.insert("password", null, cv);
            }
            catch (SQLiteException ex)
            {
                common.showBasicAlertDialog("Something has gone wrong.\n\nWe will fix this as soon as we can", false);
                Log.e("Database Errror", ex.toString());
                return false;
            }
            catch (SQLException ex)
            {
                common.showBasicAlertDialog("Something has gone wrong.\n\nWe will fix this as soon as we can", false);
                Log.e("SQL Error", ex.toString());
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
//IT GOES STRAIGHT INTO THIS CODE AFTER THE GETNEXTID METHOD RETURNS
                if (myDb.isOpen())
                {
                    myDb.close();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
```

Below is the code for the getNextId() function

```
public int getNextID(String table)
    {
        int nextID = 1;
        Cursor cursor = null;
        SQLiteDatabase myDB = null;
        try
        {
            myDB = context.openOrCreateDatabase("PasswordManager", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            cursor = myDB.rawQuery("SELECT id FROM "+table+" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1", null);
            if (cursor != null)
            {
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                nextID = cursor.getInt(0) + 1;
            }
        }
        catch (SQLiteException ex)
        {
            Log.d("GetNextID", ex.toString());
            nextID = -1;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (myDB.isOpen())
            {
                myDB.close();
            }
            if (!cursor.isClosed())
            {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
        return nextID;
    }
```

I don't understand the content values have been skipped and it goes straight into the finally.

Comment: You are closing `myDB` inside `getNextID()` then trying to insert? I guess this is not right.

Comment: Why don't you put a catch block to catch all other exceptions (Exception class), so that you will be able to see what exactly is the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps some exception other than `SQLException` and `SQLiteException` have been thrown? If you put `catch(Exception x) {...}` you will probably see.

Comment: You were right, it was the getNextId() function was throwing a different exception which was hidden until I added the catch(Exception x), it was because I forgot to check that the cursor had at least 1 row so it was throwing a cursorindexoutofbounds exception.

Answer (score 0):

First try moving the line.

```
myDb = context.openOrCreateDatabase("PasswordManager", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

below the line

```
 int rowId = common.getNextID("password");
```

in your method.  Or even better would be to add myDb as a parameter into your getNextID function so you are using the same DB reference and then don't close the DB in that function.

Add in the `catch(Exception x)` to your exceptions.

And then finally put a breakpoint inside your `getNextID` method and find out exactly which line it is breaking on.

Cheers